# insert a row into table in pl/pgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to update two tables by inserting some rows into the other. But when I try to do something like this :

```
BEGIN
    FOR id IN (SELECT id FROM table1) LOOP
     PERFORM (INSERT INTO anothertable VALUES(id));
    END LOOP;
END;
```

It gives an error I don't know why. `syntax error at or near "INTO"`.

Is it even possible to do such thing without cursors and such updating one by one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is example of bad using PERFORM and bad plpgsql programming style. You must not use a PERFORM there. You should not use a parenthesis there (PL/pgSQL is based on ADA language - not C!). Some correct patterns are:

```
FOR _id IN 
          SELECT s.id 
             FROM sometab s
LOOP
  INSERT INTO othertab(id) VALUES(_id);
END LOOP;
```

or faster (and shorter) pattern

```
INSERT INTO othertab(id)
   SELECT id 
       FROM other tab
```

I used a qualified name and prefixes to reduce a risk of conflict between SQL identifiers and PL/pgSQL variables.

Note: PERFORM is implemented as SELECT statement without result processing. So your statement was SELECT (INSERT INTO tab ...) what is unsupported feature now.

Comment: yes I am totally new to this. And if anyone had same kind of error .The was because of I wasn't using tablename() way but without paranthesis that was the problem.

Comment: all people started somewhere, no problem. I wrote a article http://postgres.cz/wiki/PL/pgSQL_%28en%29 for plpgsql beginners.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you insert it like this:

```
insert into anothertable
select id from table
```

Comment: Because it give me an error `"anothertable" is not a known variable'.

Comment: do you have a table named anothertable?

Comment: And, more important: do you have a table called `table` ?

Comment: this is inside a function maybe that I should have mentioned. and a table is not a variable as much as I know

Comment: i made them up to be more clear the real names are in another language

Comment: @wildplasser :) usually I'm changing this to table1 in answers

Comment: @ayanahmedov I understand that, but IMHO it is clearer if you choose metasyntactic names in such a way that they don't collide with keywords, or cause confusion for the human reader. For example : `insert into fruits select * from apples;`